# How can I do a nvl() to avoid errors from non existing json element?

Tags: python, json

In one word, what I'm looking for is more or less an equivalent of SQL's [nvl()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) in Python.

More info :

I have a loop retrieving data from a list of jsons. They all look the same but some of them lack some of the things I'm retrieving. Therefore, if I try to get `data['movie']['boxOffice'][0]['admissionCount']` and it isn't in the JSON, I get an error (note : this can be because 'admissionCount' doesn't exist, or because 'boxOffice' doesn't exist).

To circumvent this, here's what I'm doing for the moment :

```
try:
    admissionCount = data['movie']['boxOffice'][0]['admissionCount']
except:
    admissionCount = ''
```

It works fine, but I have ~50 fields to check that way...

I tried turning it into a function :

```
def nvl(json_element):
    try:
        out = json_element
    except:
        out = ''
    finally:
        return out

nvl(data['movie']['boxOffice'][0]['admissionCount'])
```

And then realized it was dumb, and of course I get an error.

How can I avoid having to do 50 `try/except` blocks ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `.get()` method with default for dicts

```
dict = {"a" : 1}
dict.get("a") # return 1
dict.get("b") # return None
dict.get("b", "default_obj") # return default_obj
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to safely dig down into that structure:

```
def get_deep_dict(a_dict, keys):
    value = a_dict
    for key in keys:
        try:
            value = value.get(key)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                value = value[key]
            except (IndexError, TypeError):
                return None
    return value
```

Test data and test cases:

```
data = dict(movie=dict(boxOffice=[dict(admissionCount=5)]))
admissionCount = data['movie']['boxOffice'][0]['admissionCount']

assert admissionCount == get_deep_dict(
    data, ('movie','boxOffice', 0, 'admissionCount'))

assert None == get_deep_dict(
    data, ('movie','boxOffices', 0, 'admissionCount'))

assert None == get_deep_dict(
    data, ('movie','boxOffice', 1, 'admissionCount'))
```

Comment: Right idea, but not quite: If `[0]` worked on the input, it was an array, not a dictionary. Hence `.get()` is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

While at it, we might as well do it in a generic way:

```
def get_default(base, *keys, **kwargs):
    sentinel = kwargs.get('sentinel', None)
    cur = base
    for key in keys:
        try:
            cur = cur[key]
        except (KeyError, IndexError):
            return sentinel
    return cur

data = {
    'movie': {
        'boxOffice': [
            {'admissionCount': 10},
            {'admissionCount': 20},
        ]
    }
}
```

This requires that any subobject implements proper `__getitem__()` that don't raise `KeyError` nor `IndexError` for anything else other that non-accessible (sub-)items. The dict and list objects returned from the default JSON decoder do this, but beware of custom objects.

```
print get_default(data, 'movie', 'boxOffice', 0, 'admissionCount')
>>> 10
print get_default(data, 'movie', 'boxOffice', 1, 'admissionCount')
>>> 20
print get_default(data, 'movier')
>>> None
print get_default(data, 'movie', 'boxOffice')
>>> None
print get_default(data, 'movie', 'boxOffice', 3)
>>> None
print get_default(data, 'movie', 'boxOffice', 3, 'admisssionCount', sentinel=-1)
>>> -1
```